# fetch complete data of any image wordpress

Tags: wordpress, getimagedata

I want to fetch complete data of an image. Which and how should I use any function?
Title shows title of post but I want Title of image to be displayed.
What should I do?

Comment: How do you want to fetch for images? bulk? or by post_id? or by image id? or any displaied image?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you would like to attach your image in post/page.

If you go through the Featured Image, below code will help you:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
   </a>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks.